# Deleting rows in already existing excel file by using perl

Tags: excel, perl

guys,

Iam trying to delete used rows in already existing excel file

i tried with below code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;

my $xl = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$xl->{Visible} = 0;
my $nShtsOld = $xl->{SheetsInOldWorkbook};
$xl->{SheetsInOldWorkbook} = 1;
my $wb = $xl->Workbooks->Open('C:\Users\u304079\Desktop\Test_S1_Legacy_US.xlsx');
$xl->{SheetsInOldWorkbook} = $nShtsOld;
my $sht = $wb->Sheets(o);
my $end = $sht->Usedrange->Row->Count;
print $end;

for (my $count = $end; 0 < $count; $count--) 
{
    my $cell = $sht->{Cells};
    if (!defined $cell->{Value}) 
    {
    $cell->entireRow->delete;

    } 
}

# save and exit
        $xl->SaveAs('C:\Users\u304079\Desktop\Test_S1_Legacy_US.xlsx');
        $xl->close();
```

but iam unable to do with following code getting error message as 
Can't call method "Usedrange" on an undefined value"

Comment: That error is not the only error you get. You should not leave out errors, it is extremely misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `my $sht = $wb->Sheets(o);` may be a typo.  Should that be a zero `0` instead?

Comment: yes..its a typo but tried with keeping zero 0 in it but iam getting the same error which i mentioned above